# Checking correct USER input logic

Tags: python, while-loop

Learning programming logic and having trouble with this part:

```
def player_choice(board):
    
    position = 0
    
    while True:
        try:
            position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board,position)
            position = int(input('Choose a position: (1-9) '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input! enter number of the cell between 1-9: ')
            continue
        
        return position
```

When I enter letter it keep going "Wrong input! enter number of the cell between 1-9: "

but when I enter a digit - nothing happend.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `"nothing happend"`? How do you call this function?

Comment: Your line with `position not in...` doesn't do anything you intend, probably. You need to use a conditional like an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I enter a digit - nothing happend.

And what do you expect to happen?
Your code is simply a function. Functions are executed when they are called. If called, they simply return a value. That's what normally "happens". If you expect something to be printed out, you need to, for example, call the `print(...)` function.

That comment aside, what you are trying to achieve should probably look more like this:

```
def player_choice(board):    
    while True:
        try:            
            position = int(input('Choose a position: (1-9) '))
            if 1 <= position <= 9 and space_check(board, position):
                return position
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input! enter number of the cell between 1-9: ')
```